# OkHttp и завершение приложения

Tags: java, okhttp

Использую `OkHttp` для выполнения асинхронного запроса:

```
public class Main {
    private static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run();
    }

    public static void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }

                System.out.println(response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения этого кода на консоль выводится содержимое ответа от сервера, но после этого приложение не завершается, хотя хотелось бы, чтобы оно завершалось.

Насколько я понимаю, это происходит из-за того, что в процессе работы `OkHttp` создает поток, который, почему-то не завершается автоматически.

**Вопроса два:**

Почему приложение не завершается?

Как корректно завершить работу приложения после отработки одного из коллбэков? `System.exit(0);` или?

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что приложение завершилось? И, собственно, зачем это нужно? Остановите ненужные сервисы и потоки, этого будет достаточно. Из памяти приложение операционка выгрузить сама.

Comment: "Как вы проверяете, что приложение завершилось?" - Запускаю в Intellij IDEA. Если приложение завершилось, то в консоль выводится: `Process finished with exit code 0` и кнопка остановки приложения становится неактивной. В данном же случае все наоборот: приложение выполняется, выводит результат и все, дальше просто висит, можно вручную кнопкой `Stop` завершить.

Comment: По поводу зачем это надо - меня смущает тот факт, что после логического завершения приложения, оно остается в памяти. Такое ощущение, что какой-то поток чего-то ждет. Но я явно не создаю потоков, ими управляет `OkHTTP`. PS: это не андроид.

Comment: ага, не андроид, только сейчас сообразил. извините.